# How to deserialize XML-content to ABAP data fields properly?

Tags: xml, xslt, abap

When reading the XML content in ABAP internal table fields via XSLT, sometimes the value cannot be read or an exception appears: **Error during deserialization**. How can I select the right data type for ABAP itab fields, if I now the XML data type?
e.g.

---

### XML Data Type.......|......Format....|.............ABAP Data Type..........

---

string 250..........................|..........Text............|.....................?

---

string 250.........................|..Date yyy-mm-dd..|.....................?

---

string 250.........................|.Date PARAM-4....|......................?

---

string 250.........................|..Time hh:mm........|....................?

---

string 250........................|..Number z9(4)........|...................?

---

string 250........................|.. Number 9(4).........|................. ?

---

string 250........................|..Number 9(7)..........|.................?

---

string 250........................|..Number 9(6)...........|................?

---

string 250........................|..Number z9(2).........|..................?

---

string 250........................|..Number 9(5)...........|.................?

---

string 250........................|..Number d9(2).........|.................?

---

string 250........................|..Number 9(19).........|.................?

---

string 250........................|..Number 9(17) v9(2)|.................?

---

string 250........................|.Number Delco price|.................?

---

string 250........................|Number Delco amount|.................?

---

string 250........................|Number customer invoice amount|.................?

---

string 250........................|..Number PARAM-3.......|.................?

---

**Please note that**

- **xml** = version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"
- **PARM-3** = Decimal separator used in field formats “,” or “.”
- **PARM-4** = Date format used in field formats “dd-mm-yyyy” or “yyyy-mm-dd”

**Number format:**

- 9(X): an X-digit integer formatted with leading zeros and no sign e.g. 9(2) "01”
- v: implicit decimal place e.g. 9(2)v9(2) formats 1.1 as “0110”
- d: decimal mark as specified by PARM-3, either , or . e.g. 9(2)d9(2) formats 1.1 as “01,10” or “01.10”
- z: supress leading zeros and include sign if negative
  e.g. z9(6)d9(2) “ -1.10”

  %: include per cent character e.g. z9(2)d9(2)% “ 20.00%”
- Delco price: z9(X)d9(Y) where Y is BillingDocument/DeliverCompany/CurrencyPricingMinorUnits and X is the
  number of remaining digits in the field
- Delco amount: z9(X)d9(Y) where Y is
  BillingDocument/DeliverCompany/CurrencyMinorUnits and X is the number of
  remaining digits in the field
- Customer invoice amount: z9(X)d9(Y) where Y is
  BillingDocument/InvoiceCustomer/MinorUnits and X is the number of
  remaining digits in the field

Comment: Just put your XML data and your XSLT here, otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

How do you deserialize the XML? You don't have complex type in the XML file as I understand, or do you?

You can try this for both actually( complex types and regular types):

```
DATA: xml_utils TYPE REF TO if_ixml.xml_utils = cl_ixml=>create( ).
      xml_stream_factory TYPE REF TO if_ixml_stream_factory.xml_stream_factory = xml_utils->create_stream_factory( ).
DATA: xml_input_stream TYPE REF TO if_ixml_istream.xml_input_stream = xml_stream_factory->create_istream_uri( system_id = 'file://test.xml' ).
DAtA: example_data type z_s_your_structure.

" Deserialize XML 
CALL TRANSFORMATION id 
   SOURCE XML       = xml_input_stream 
   RESULT data_node = example_data.
```

For more information, you can check these links, [1](https://blogs.sap.com/2005/02/24/abap-serialization-part-i-quick-n-easy/), [2](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/02/21/three-different-ways-to-serialize-and-deserialize-complex-abap-data/).